# Unsetting a value from local storage on click

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm using local storage to save the id as seen below, it works as it's suppose to. When I click on the anchor it sends the value into an array. The problem is when I click it again, it saves that same value again into the same array. I would like to take that value out of the array on the second click. So basically I want it to act as a toggle.

```
    $(".favorites").click(function() {

        var favorite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' ));

        if (favorite == undefined)
        {
            favorite = Array();
        }
        favorite.push($(this).attr('data-petid'));

        localStorage.setItem( 'favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite) );
        JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' ) );
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your description is not clear at first, you mean take the value out of an array, right?

```
$(".favorites").click(function() {

    var favorite = localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' );
    var petid = $(this).attr('data-petid');
    var index;

    favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];

    if ((index = favorite.indexOf(petid)) === -1) {
      favorite.push(petid);
    } else {
      favorite.splice(index, 1);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite) );
 }
```

Comment: This works, but for only one instance of the value. I'm trying to add a whole list of favorites to an array (favorites). And if the user decides to go back and unfavor a pet, that instance will be taken out of local storage.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, but you def answered it with this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition where if favorite is not undefined or null, you're only returning the value.

```
$(".favorites").click(function() {

        var favorite = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' ));

        if (favorite === undefined || favorite === null)
        {
            favorite = Array();
            favorite.push($(this).attr('data-petid'));

            localStorage.setItem( 'favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite) );
            JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' ) );
        }
        else{
            alert('favorite');
        }

   });
```